# WinJS: Is it posible to add a budge to a Pivot Item programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I´m building a Windows Phone 8.1 app with WinJS and I have a PivotItem inside a Pivot element:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot">
    <div class="conversations"
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem"
         data-win-res="{winControl: {'header': 'conversations'}}">
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm unsuccessfully trying to add a budge next to the title to show unread conversations count similar to Facebook notification count.

Already tried:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/conversations.html", {
ready: function (element, options) {
        var span = document.createElement('DIV')
        span.innerHTML = "<span>5</span>";

        var p = document.querySelector(".conversations");
        p.appendChild(span);
    }
}
```

And also with CSS:

```
.conversations ::after{
    content: "3";
}
```

But still no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workarround:

```
var pivotHeader = document.querySelector(".win-pivot-headers");

if(pivotHeader != null)
{
        var headers = pivotHeader.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            var badge = document.createElement('span');
            badge.id = "unseenConversationsBudge";
            badge.innerHTML = "10";

            headers[i].appendChild(badge);
            WinJS.UI.Animation.fadeIn(badge);
        }
    }
```

And then handle it in the inicialization event of the app and animationstart/animationend events of the header item. Also had to check and remove span if existed to avoid repetition.